# Python tells me that my if statement contains a syntax error

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was writing some code today, just a little script that takes up to three strings and messes around with them, reverses them, and puts them in different orders. When I try to run my code I get an invalid syntax error, but I don't really know why.

```
ammount = int(input("How many strings would you like to input? 1, 2 or 3?")
# Getting user input
if ammount == 1:
    input1 = str(input("Please enter the first string"))
elif ammount == 2:
    user_input_1 = str(input("Please enter the first string"))
    user_input_2 = str(input("Please enter the second string"))
elif ammount == 3:
    user_input_1 = str(input("Please enter the first string"))
    user_input_2 = str(input("Please enter the second string"))
    user_input_3 = str(input("Please enter the third string"))
```

Comment: Hi.  When you need help with an error, _always_ post the relevant part of the error, erring on the side of more information .

Comment: I will keep that in mind thank you

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a closing `)` after casting to an int

```
ammount = int(input("How many strings would you like to input? 1, 2 or 3?"))
```

Comment: Don't forget to mark the question as answered. so the people that helped you get the points.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably receiving the error on the if statement because you are missing a closing paren `)` at the end of the line right before your `if ammount ==1:` statement. The error falls on the if statement because python interpreter thinks you are trying to put the if statement inside of the cast to int function and it doesn't belong there